# How to Use Custom yolov4 weights in iOS app

Tags: ios, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, yolov4

I following these steps:

1. Obtained YOLO v4 weights after training on my custom dataset
2. Converted weights to TensorFlow checkpoints
3. Converted Tensorflow checkpoint to tflite
4. Quantized tflite
5. I was using tflite [samples](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-ios/#0) and imported custom tflite to xcode project

But I'm getting a crash:

```
Failed to create the interpreter with error: Failed to create the interpreter.
ObjectDetection/ViewController.swift:56: Fatal error: Failed to load model
2022-02-28 13:28:22.850305+0530 ObjectDetection[9505:3901451] 
ObjectDetection/ViewController.swift:56: Fatal error: Failed to load model
```

I tested my tflite weights and its working fine

Comment: Can you share details on what customization/changes you did to the app to properly load your model.
Also, is there any other messages in the Log.
Thanks

Comment: @KarimNosseir I imported the tflite weights to the sample object detention example app, changed the input size to the expected input size of network and changes the labels file to the custom labels (classes)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this space for solution https://github.com/ankits16/CVRecorderFinal/blob/main/README.md